# How to know if the WM_PAINT must erase background? windows api

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to log the paint messages to solve a problem, and I need a way to know if the WM_PAINT message has to erase the background, 
so I did this inside the WM_PAINT processing:

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
//code to output the Invalid RECT is ommited.....
if(ps.fErase){
    //output true
}else{
    //output false
};
```

the `ps.rcPaint` has correct values but the `ps.fErase` is always "false" even when I call `InvalidateRect(hwnd,0,true);` where `hwnd` is the window that I log the WM_PAINT message for
here is some [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbevi.jpg)

I want to know if the invalid reign painting request including erase background like i did with the last `InvalidateRect(hwnd,0,1);` What I'm doing Wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system sends `WM_ERASEBKGND` before `WM_PAINT` if the background needs erasing. If you're not handling this message then it will be going through to `DefWindowProc` which will erase the background automatically.

You need to handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` and return `0` to indicate to the system that the background has not been erased yet. It will then give you another chance in `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: thank you very much , yes now it returns TRUE, but how I distinguish -inside WM_PAINT processing - between if the WM_paint message is caused because of `InvalidateRect(hwnd,0,**1**);` or because of `InvalidateRect(hwnd,0,**0**); ` since both calls will generate `WM_ERASEBKGND` and `WM_PAINT` ?

Comment: Passing `FALSE` to `InvalidateRect` shouldn't cause the background to need erasing.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right I was missing something elsewhere in my code that causing the erase to the background , thank you very much for your help  :)

Comment: I just realized I didn't upvote your help, thank you :) I left C and windows API and now play with PHP, have a good day Jonathan